# Dual boot Ubuntu partition not shown on windows disk management, how can I fix this?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I did not create a partition before installing my Ubuntu 20.04 dual boot, its not showing on my windows disk management. I think this is the reason its showing invalid volume when I try to update my grub in Ubuntu terminal as it is showing invalid volume error when I 'sudo update-grub'.
How can I fix this?

I saw some guide that I have to change the simple volume type to NFTS but I cant change the type as it is combined with my windows drive in one partition.

Comment: Your details aren't very clear. Please use exact terms and commands and the verbatim text of errors. When installing Ubuntu in dual boot configuration, you don't need to do any of the actions you suggest in your question details. I suggest that you start over, following the [official tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop). Read the tutorial before starting, so you are familiar with what actually needs to be done. You'll see on step 6 there is a link to an authoritative source with additional help for dual boot configurations with Windows.

Comment: Thank you! will take a look now.

Comment: Generally, as long as you have unpartitioned free space big enough for Ubuntu, and you've booted the USB as UEFI, and Fast Startup has been disabled in Windows, then the Ubuntu installer will give you an "Install alongside Windows" option and in that case you can just click through the menus and the next time you boot Ubuntu you will get a choice of OS in GRUB

Comment: Thats the problem, I did not create a empty partition before installing ubuntu. I chose the 'install alongside Windows' and now the ubuntu seems to be in the same partition as my Windows drive and I do not know how to separate them. Ubuntu installation went smoothly, now I cant update my grub cause the partition is 'locked' by windows?
I update grub cause I downloaded a new kernel RT patch.

Comment: Thanks! I have found the problem, my Disk 1 in my disk management is showing nothing and has a red cross, I guess its installed inside Disk 1. Are you familiar with RT kernel installation?

Comment: I cant mark as solved.

Comment: Add a screenshot of the app Gparted after booting Ubuntu. If your computer can't boot Ubuntu from the internal drive, boot Ubuntu from the installation USB, using the try Ubuntu option.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found the problem, my Disk 1 in my disk management is showing nothing and has a red cross, I guess its installed inside Disk 1 and my Disk 1 is corrupted.